# macos monterey: PF load anchor syntax error

Tags: networking, qemu, macos, nat, pf

I am trying to make a NAT interface to connect tap0 to the internet for QEMU. So far I've made a bridge and connected tap0 to it:

```
sudo ifconfig bridge1 create
sudo ifconfig bridge1 addm tap0
sudo Ifconfig bridge1 up
```

Now I'm trying to NAT bridge1 to the internet (I think en0) using PF.

I have added an anchor to my pf.conf file:

```
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
anchor PF_NAT_Anchor
```

My anchor file:

```
pass out on en0 inet from bridge1 to any nat-to (en0)
```

However, each time I try to load the file I get a Syntax error:

```
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules
present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
PATH_TO_FILE/PF_NAT_Anchor:1: syntax error
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
```

I've looked over the Anchor file but cannot find the error. All my scripts are slightly modified versions from https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/nat.html#status
and
https://srobb.net/pf.html
Please help and thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

To whoever needs this in the future, I guess there are different versions of PF. https://calomel.org/pf_config.html helped me. The line that loaded for me was:

```
nat on en0 from bridge1:network to any -> (en0)
```